# static and non-static vs generics and wildcard in Java

Tags: java, generics, static, wildcard

consider the following example

```
class test<E>{
    public int getNum(int i){
        return i;
    }

    public E getNum1(E i){
        return i;
    }

    public static <E> E getNum(E i){
        return i;
    }
    }
```

First method declaration: return type is known

second method declaration: return type is some unknown

third method declaration: return type is some unknown + Static

question: when static method is used for generics, the type parameter `<E>` must be specified. why is it so?or what exactly the type parameter mean and whats its purpose? we dont have type parameter when the method is non-static, although in this case we have `<E>` in class declaration such as `public class <E> {...}`

consider this on wild-card

```
//This does not compile, how to make it correct
    public static  getIndex(List<?>, int index){
        return list.get(index);
    }

    public static <E> E getIndex1(List<E> list, int index){
        return list.get(index);
    }
```

Again, the first method does not compile. I dont know how to make it compile using unbounded wildcards for return type

what is the difference between the two method declaration above?

wildcard `?` indicates any type and `E` indicates some unknown type.

how does that matter since `any type` is `some unknown type` correct?

Comment: `E` indicates some unknown type that you can name and refer to later.  `?` indicates some unknown type that you don't name and can't refer to later.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I stole your quote for my own purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*question: when static method is used for generics, the type parameter  must be specified. why is it so?or what exactly the type parameter mean and whats its purpose? we dont have type parameter when the method is non-static, although in this case we have  in class declaration such as public class  {...}*

A `static` method doesn't belong to an instance, it belongs to a class. A class doesn't have a generic type (an instance does).

So it wouldn't make sense to have

```
class test<E>{
    public static E getNum(E i){
        return i;
    }
}
```

You'll get `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E`.

The type parameter in the class declaration is for instances

```
test<String> anInstance = new test<String>();
```

---

This

```
//This does not compile, how to make it correct
public static  getIndex(List<?>, int index){
    return list.get(index);
}
```

because you haven't provided a return type and the `List<?>` parameter doesn't have a variable declaration.

---

*how does that matter since `any type` is `some unknown type` correct?*

When you do a generic type declaration like

```
public class Test<E> {}
```

`E` isn't an unknown type. It is a well defined type that is chosen when you create an instance.

```
Test<String> test = new Test<>();
```

`E` is `String`.

To quote [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664780/static-and-non-static-vs-generics-and-wildcard-in-java/18664797?noredirect=1#comment27487936_18664780)

> E indicates some unknown type that you can name and refer to later. ?
>   indicates some unknown type that you don't name and can't refer to
>   later.

---

You would gain a lot from reading the [official Java tutorial on Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: so what the type parameter means?

Comment: @user The type parameter declaration on a method is required to define a generic type that only that method will use. A type parameter declaration on a class is required to define the type parameter that instance methods and fields can use.

Comment: how to provide return declaration for wildcard? I know I did not provide return, but having `?` as return type does not make sense. further this does not compile either `public static<E>  E getIndex(List<? extends E>, int index){
  return list.get(index);
 }`

Comment: @user1988876 If you're using a wildcard, you cannot declare a return of the **wildcard type because you don't know what that is (it's a wildcard)**. The line you showed doesn't compiled because you haven't give a variable for the `List` parameter.